# Android TextureView startDragAndDrop() method shows an empty Drag View

Tags: android, android-textureview

I have a custom `TextureView` that all the rendering is handled using OpenGL ES through JNI/C++.

Pretty much everything is working, aside the `startDragAndDrop` method. Which gives me an empty drag view...

Looking at the source code of the `View.DragShadowBuilder` class I found out that all the rendering logic for the creation of the drag view is inside the  method `public void onDrawShadow(Canvas canvas)`; which basically it passes the canvas to the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method of the view.

Now the problem is that `TextureView` doesn't implement the `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` method. And I'm unable to override it since it's final...

Is there any way that I can render the content of my `TextureView` in this canvas...

Right now I'm able to create a bitmap using a `ByteBuffer` and copying the buffer from OpenGL. But again I don't know how to pass this bitmap to the canvas...

Answer (score 1):

It should be a simple matter of calling canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, null); inside onDrawShadow. If that doesn't work you may need to check the data format in the ByteBuffer that you pass to the Bitmap when you call bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer to ensure that it matches the Bitmap.Config.

Comment: Mmmmm I don't know why I didn't think about it, but yeah it worked... The drawback is that if my custom `TextureView` is inside a `ViewGroup` such as `CardView`. We can only render the Parent view (which will contained an empty area since it doesn't implement `onDrawCanvas`); or we can only render our `TextureView`...